# Does `std::mutex` and `std::lock` guarantee memory synchronisation in inter-processor code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, openmp

I'm currently using openMP to write code running on multi-core nodes. openMP has a specific memory model which guarantees that memory is synchronised between threads running on different cores when a lock is acquired.

I consider using C++11 constructs (`std::thread` with `std::mutex` and `std::lock`) instead of openMP (because of their larger flexibility) and wonder if/how memory synchronisation between processors is guaranteed here? And if not, how can I enforce it?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  It almost looks like your asking how to do multithreaded programming.

Comment: Some synchronization is guaranteed, some isn't. This question is really vague.

Comment: Do you mean memory synchronisations of the `mutex` itself or of the data accesses in the code protected by the mutex?

Comment: C++ doesn't care about cores or processors (other than the `hardware_concurrency` function, perhaps). If it synchronizes between threads, it synchronizes between threads.

Comment: Seems like a clear question to me - I assume he's asking if c++ mutexes imply a full memory barrier?

Comment: @JohnB: The the answer is also simple: **No.** However, *memory is synchronized between cores* isn't really a description of a full memory barrier.

Comment: No, I just assumed that was what he meant.

Comment: @KillianDS the second of your points is exactly what I meant (of course). As far as I understand, the compiler doesn't know which data are protected by the mutex, does it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard makes the following guarantees about synchronization of `std::mutex`, in §30.4.1.2[thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/6-25

> The expression m.lock() shall be well-formed and have the following semantics
>
> *Synchronization*: Prior unlock() operations on the same object shall synchronize with this operation.

And, likewise,

> The expression m.unlock() shall be well-formed and have the following semantics
>
> *Synchronization*: This operation synchronizes with subsequent lock operations that obtain ownership on the same object.

(Where "synchronizes with" is a specific term explained in $1.10, although it's much easier to understand by reading *C++ Concurrency In Action*)

Comment: Which suggests that the presence (or absence) of multiple processors does not matter... It is up to the implementation to enforce these guarantees.

Comment: can you refer me to a web resource that explains what "synchronizes with". Does this imply cache coherence on a multi-core node?

Comment: @Walter in brief, it means every store made by the thread that released the mutex becomes visible to the thread that acquired the mutex, but not to other thread. It implies a release barrier and an acquire barrier, or their equivalents.